# Scaling the firemonkey printer canvas fontsize to represent windows font size

Tags: delphi, printing, fonts, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

**Problem :**
When I use the same font settings for the default `FMX: Printer` that i used for the `VCL` printer,
the printed text comes out much smaller, for all different sizes. When i scale The fontsize * **1.33**, the font is about the right size.

How do i how do I calculate this factor in which i need to scale the font? And what is it dependent on? Or why are the fontsize different for Firemonkey/vcl.
So i can represent the normal font size.

Changing the DPI does not seem to influence this problem.( read : same problem on all DPI).

Comment: How do you know which one is the right size?